# Jquery form submit behavior not understandable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing code for a small webproject using js and jquery. In it, at some point, onclicking a button, i create a dialog. the dialog has a form within it with a name field and some number fields. I am supposed to check user inputs and send them to server, along with appending the name field to a list in the browser, to intimate user, one more item has been added. Two strange things are happening -

1) After posting the form, the dialog box closes on its own without me issuing a dialog('close') anywhere in the submit button handler.

2) The name entry doesn't get appended to the list. Its as if the whole page refreshes after the submit. With the original default entries of the list of names.

Anyone has any ideas on why this is happening? Would post some code for your aid.Please don't suggest to use Ajax instead. I think this reflects some fundamental flaw in my understanding of JS ways and would like to clear it first than just switching to some other technology.

```
    <div id='dialog' title='Define New Matrix'>
<form name='form1' id='form1'  method='post'>
<fieldset>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type='text' name='nameofmatrix' id='Name' class='whitepanes'><br>
    <label for="a11">a11</label>
    <input type="text" name='a11' id='a11' class='whitepanes number-field'><br>
    <label for="a22">a22</label>
    <input type="text" name='a22' id='a22' class='whitepanes number-field'><br>
    <button id='submit_button'>Submit</button>
    <button id='cancel_button'>cancel</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
    <p id='tip' style='color:red;'><i>All fields are required</i></p>
</div>
<script>
    //#button_define is a button on whose clicking the dialog opens. 
            $('#button_define').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#tip').html("<p style='color:red; font-size:small'>All fields are      mandatory</p>");
    });

    $('#submit_button,#cancel_button').button();

    $('#cancel_button').on('click',function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });

    $('#submit_button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name=$('input[name=nameofmatrix]').val();
        //Validate is a function which returns a bool if validation proceeds     correctly
        var isCorrect = Validate();
        if(isCorrect){
        //if validated correctly then add to list

            $('#form1').submit();   
            //$('#dialog').dialog('close');
            $('#selectable').append("<li class='ui-widget-content'>",name,"</li>"); 
        } 

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should first wrap your code inside document.ready function. Open up Firebug to see what errors come up in console...

Comment: I have wrapped it. the actual code and html is too big and irrelevant to this question so only posted part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its as if the whole page refreshes after the post. with the original entries.

That's precisely what happens.  Though I'm not sure where you're submitting the POST request *to* since there's no `action` attribute on your `form`.  But a standard non-AJAX request triggered by a `form` sends the request to the server and then renders the response from the server.  If the response is this same page again, then this same page will be rendered again.

JavaScript isn't going to remember the state of the previous page when it loads this new response.  Even if they're the same page, they're two separate responses from the server.  So...

> 1) After posting the form, the dialog box closes on its own without me issuing a dialog('close') anywhere in the submit button handler.

The dialog isn't closing.  After the page refreshes you're in an *entirely new* page context.  It didn't close, it just hasn't been opened yet in this context.

> 2) The name entry doesn't get appended to the list.

There's nothing that would cause this to happen when the page loads, so in the new page context it doesn't happen.  Your server-side code would need to include this content in the response to the POST request.

> I think this reflects some fundamental flaw in my understanding of JS ways and would like to clear it first than just switching to some other technology.

Included in that misunderstanding is the fact that AJAX *is* part of JavaScript.  (The "J" in "AJAX" stands for "JavaScript.")  It's not "switching to some other technology."  It's taking advantage of the capabilities of the technology you're already using.  All AJAX does, really, is send requests and receive responses to/from the server without refreshing the page context.

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly appending the `name`. The concatenation operator is not a `comma`, but a `+` in javascript:

```
$('#selectable').append("<li class='ui-widget-content'>" + name + "</li>");
```

Next, the form refreshes because you are submitting the form using `$('#form1').submit();`. If you do not want the page to refresh while submitting, use ajax.

Comment: well, you are right in pointing out the append. But it doesn't solve the problem. Even now after refreshing that append is gone. So are you saying this is bound to happen and only way out is ajax? How do people persist their dom manipulations then without ajax during form submits?

Comment: they submit data to server, store in session, then read them when page refreshes